How to convert http.wsgi.Response object to dict in gunicorn log
I want to add a custom atom to atoms of gunicorn in logging class that indicates the response of the request. Something like this:
from gunicorn.glogging import Logger

class MyLog(Logger):

    def atoms(self, resp, req, environ, request_time):
        from django.urls import resolve
        atoms = super().atoms(resp, req, environ, request_time)
        url_name = resolve(environ.get('PATH_INFO')).url_name
        # This is what I want to do:
        if url_name == 'xxxx':
            response_body = ...  # TODO
            atoms['R'] = response_body.get('yyy')

Is there any way to convert resp in atoms function to real response (in text or json)?
